# Modify logo + copyright on Bing Maps REST API

Tags: api, bing-maps

I'm attempting to use Bing Maps REST API to track traffic flow over time.
To do so, I mosaic many 640x640 pixel tiles together, using [this template](https://github.com/cran/RgoogleMaps/blob/master/R/GetMap.R)
The issue is that when I mosaic all these tiles, the Bing map logo and API obscure many parts of the map, like this:
[image]

I know that it is possible to modify the logo with Bing Maps V8 Web Control by accessing the [MapOptions Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712646.aspx) , but I'm not sure how to access these with the API Rest (newbie with REST services over here).

For the record, I am aware of the terms and conditions of use for the Bing REST API, and am not planning to display these maps without a logo (I just would rather not have 50 logos/copyright info per map).

Comment: Was there any progress on getting / removing the logo? I am working on something similar, but in my case I am not using the traffic, just using the Aerial view, and the logo comes up about 40 times in a single "mosaic". Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to hack this together using Bing Maps in a way that is against it terms of use, take a look at Azure Maps. Azure Maps provides access to their traffic tiles which would be a lot easier to work with. They also use a data provider who has better traffic data. Here are some details: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/trafficservice/gettrafficflowtile

Details on how to get a subscription key can be found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-manage-account-keys

Azure Maps has high free limits and low pricing as well which might help. Find out more here: https://azure.com/maps